# An explanation of Whirlpool C implementation - or the general algorithm

Tags: c, algorithm, cryptography, whirlpool

Anyone got a tutorial on the designers concept implementation of Whirlpool in C, or the Whirlpool algorithm in general? I find the source code hard to understand, mostly because I do not know anything about the algorithm. I am not a cryptographer, nor am I a good mathematican, so their documentation kind of went over my head...

The implementation and other documentation can be found [here](http://www.larc.usp.br/~pbarreto/WhirlpoolPage.html)

Initially I was just searching for a free (public domain) implementation to use in a project, but I figured I better know something about it as well... Currently I do not even know how to use it.

Comment: Well if the source code is complex and you are not good at maths then you shouldn't try to code a cryptographic algorithm by yourself...Either use their code (or modify it) or find a library because otherwise you'll likely do a bad implementation with security issues... Any particular reason to use that one specifically ?

Comment: Its better ask it in http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Loïc: Exactly, I'm not going to code one myself. I'm aiming at using the proof-of-concept implementation I posted a link to. I just want to understand what it does.  @SaeedAlg: Okay. Had no idea that site existed...

Comment: I was going to suggest Wikipedia since it's usually good for this sort of thing (ex: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard), but apparently the article on Whirlpool isn't very in-depth.